# На чем написать MMO игровой сервер? (по типу (agar.io)

Tags: c++, веб-программирование, сервер, клиент-сервер

Хочу сделать браузерную игру по типу ИО-игр (agar.io, slither.io и т.д.). 
Сервер должен заниматся трудоемкими расчетами физики объектов в 2д пространстве.
Клиент - грубо говоря "контроллер", что отрисовывает перемещение и события.
На клиентской стороне думаю использовать pixi.js для отрисовки.
А вот с сервером проблемы...

**Суть вопроса такова:**

- На чем писать многопользовательский сервер по типу ИО-игр (имею ввиду
  библиотеки/фреймворки/прочее под С++)?
- Если С++ не годен, то что есть получше (связки язиков, фреймворков...)?
- Возможно ви можете предложить лучшый вариант для клиента?

Comment: Что такое `ИО-игр`? Какие требования к серверу? Если ни каких, то без разницы на чем писать.

Comment: @VTT, Что такое ИО-игр? https://diep.io/
 Какие требования к серверу? Быстрые расчети 2Д физики
Извиняюсь за не ясность)

Comment: Никаких трудоемких расчетов тут нет. Простейшие столкновения кружков. Так что писать можно даже на js.

Comment: Это так, но таких расчётов будет ОЧЕНЬ много, поэтому я выбрал С++, но не знаю хорошей сетевой библиотеки для этой задачи. @VTT Можете посоветовать какую-то?

Comment: Что значит много? На таком сервере вряд ли будет сидеть больше пары десятков игроков, соответственно объем расчетов будет мизерный.

Comment: Опять же, ето так, НО будет много ботов которие нужно считать